# Compress or convert .mov to lighter format

Tags: transcoding

My camera records videos in `.mov` format, what can I use to edit out the audio and lower it's size in a Windows environment?

Comment: Note that `.mov` is just a container. What you're really looking to do is change the compression. A QuickTime video file (`.mov`) can have any number of different codecs used to compress it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't mention whether you're using a Mac or Windows, but...

You could use a tool like [MPEG Streamclip](http://www.squared5.com) to change the format of the video, or strip off the audio.  Works on both Mac or Windows.

Comment: I use a Linux-based OS, but this question applies to Windows users, thanks!